# How do you use {StaticResource key} if the property is not exposed as a XAML attribute?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, uwp

For instance, instead of this:

```
<Color x:Key="MyColor">#FFF</Color>
```

I want this:

```
<Color x:Key="MyColor" ColorAttribute={StaticResource MyBaseColor}/>
```

But the problem is 'ColorAttribute' is not exposed.

Also in the case of `<FontFamily>PathToMyFont</FontFamily>`, I want to point to a base font so that I only change one resource every time I want to do so.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use MyBaseColor directly?

Answer (score 1):

```
<Color x:Key="MyBaseColor">#FFF</Color>    
<StaticResource x:Key="MyColor" ResourceKey="MyBaseColor" />
<StaticResource x:Key="MyOtherColor" ResourceKey="MyBaseColor" />

<FontFamily x:Key="MyBaseFontFamily">...</FontFamily>
<StaticResource x:Key="MyFontFamily" ResourceKey="MyBaseFontFamily" />
<StaticResource x:Key="MyOtherFontFamily" ResourceKey="MyBaseFontFamily" />
```

And so on, etc.

Comment: I got "dynamic resource can only be used with dependency property" error.

Comment: Are you using dynamic resources? You shouldn't be, in UWP at least

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of is most likely not what you'll like (but it works). First take this new StaticResource Extension:

```
public class StaticResourceColorChannelExtension : StaticResourceExtension
{
    public object Channel { get; set; }

    public StaticResourceColorChannelExtension()
    {
    }

    public StaticResourceColorChannelExtension(object resourceKey)
        : base(resourceKey)
    {
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        object value = base.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
        string channelStr = (string)Channel;

        Color color = (Color)value;

        switch(channelStr)
        {
            case "A":
                return color.A;
            case "R":
                return color.R;
            case "G":
                return color.G;
            case "B":
                return color.B;
        }

        return (byte)0;
    }
}
```

In XAML you use it like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Color x:Key="MyColor">#FFFF00FF</Color>
    <Color x:Key="MyColor2"
           A="{local:StaticResourceColorChannel MyColor,
                                                Channel=A}"
           B="{local:StaticResourceColorChannel MyColor,
                                                Channel=B}"
           G="{local:StaticResourceColorChannel MyColor,
                                                Channel=G}"
           R="{local:StaticResourceColorChannel MyColor,
                                                Channel=R}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyColor2Brush"
                     Color="{StaticResource MyColor2}" />
</Window.Resources>
```